# Sorting using a helper function?

Tags: python, sorting

I have two variables: `numbers = [8, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]` and `group = [2, 3, 5, 7]`. The `group` variable are the numbers that should be first in the numbers list if found.

What I want to know is what returning (0,x) and (1,x) have to do with sorting the numbers based on priority from the `group` variable.

```
def sort_priority(values, group):
    def helper(x):
        if x in group:
            return (0, x)
        return (1, x)
    values.sort(key=helper)
```

Comment: It's not `(0,1)` and `(1,0)` it's `(0,x)` and `(1,x)`. Tuples are sorted through each element so, this ensures all of the members of the group `(0,x)` are returned first by increasing `x` then all the non-group members `(1,x)` sorted ascending by `x`

Comment: `(0, x) < (1, x)` is true for all `x`

Comment: @AChampion changed it.

Comment: Please, don't edit your source code directly to add corrections.

Comment: @J.Piquard, sorry about that. I merely changed a little typo pointed out by AChampion.

Comment: As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) states: "_key_ specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element: `key=str.lower`." This means that whatever the `key` function returns will be used to compare the items of the sequence in order to determine the resulting order. When a tuple is returned, each value in it is compared with the corresponding value in any one it is compared against, so `(0, x)` will also be considered less than `(1, x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duples are sorted in order:

```
(0, 10) < (0, 50) < (1, 10) < (1, 50)
```

By using `key=helper`, it uses the `helper` function to transform the input while sorting. `helper` takes the regular number (say, `7`) and then wraps it up in a tuple that indicates whether it's in `group` (in this case `(0, 7)`). Then when there's a number that's no in `group`, it'll be forced to appear afterwards (`(1, 6)`, for example).

Comment: Ok, so that's how the sort method sorts the items in a list; via tuples comparisons like the one you demonstrated?

Comment: The `key` key to `sort` lets you transform the input. In this case the input is transformed into tuples. `sort` then compares its input using the standard `<` and `>`, which for tuples works the way I described.

Answer (score 1):

While @tsm has answered the question, it's worth looking at a simpler example that achieves the same effect. This example assumes that all the ints in the numbers list are less than 100 (so the original code is better, but I'm offering this simpler example just to try and make things clearer).

Basically what this example does is to add 100 to any number that is *not* in the group list - that gives non-group numbers a higher sort value. So, a number X that is in the group has a sort order of X, while a number Y that is *not* in the group has a sort order of 100+Y.

```
numbers = [8, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
group = [2, 3, 5, 7]

def sort_priority(values, group):
    def helper(x):
        if x in group:
            return x
        else:
            return 100 + x
    values.sort(key=helper)

print("Before:", numbers)
sort_priority(numbers, group)
print("After: ", numbers)
```

So, the number list to be sorted is: [8, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]

But the sort is based on a second, transformed list: [100+8, 3, 100+1, 2, 5, 100+4, 7, 100+6]