# Explanation of custom key (helper) sorting function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I encountered the following example in a tutorial I watched recently.

We want to sort these numbers:

```
numbers = [8, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
```

prioritising the ones belonging to the following group:

```
group = {2, 3, 5, 7}
```

So the helper (sorting key) function implemented by the author was the following:

```
def helper(x):
    if x in group:
        return (0, x)
    return (1, x)
```

and it sorts by calling

```
numbers.sort(key=helper)
```

I can't seem to get my head around this `return (0,x)` vs. `return (1,x)` which most likely is something easy to explain (but perhaps I am missing an element about how the sorting helper function works)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort-priority in python with help of closure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52472419/sort-priority-in-python-with-help-of-closure-function)

Comment: Also: [Sorting using a helper function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40962691/sorting-using-a-helper-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What that key function does is, instead of comparing

```
[8, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
```

it compares

```
[(0, 8), (1, 3), (0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 5), (0, 4), (1, 7), (0, 6)]
```

Tuples are sorted lexicographically, meaning that the first elements are compared first.  If they differ, the comparison stop.  If they're the same, the second elements are compared.

This has the effect of bringing all numbers in `group` to the front (in numerical order) followed by the rest of the numbers (also in numerical order).

Answer (score 1):

Well, `(0, x)` is smaller than `(1, x)`. In short, Python will first compare the first element, if they are the same, then the second, then the third...

Is it clear enough? I mean, in your example, all elements in that group will be considered as smaller than the elements which are not in that group.

Answer (score 0):

When the following line executes `numbers.sort(key=helper)`, an iterator iterates over each element of the list `number`.
While iterating, for each element, it makes a call to the `helper` method with the element.
If this element is a part of the group, it returns `(0, element)`.
If it isn't a part of the group, it returns `(1, element)`.
Now, while sorting, the elements to be sorted are `[(0,x), (1,x), (0,x)...]` not the actual elements.
It compares two tuples in the list and checks if the values are `>` or `<` or `=`.
While comparing two tuples, it first compares them based on the value at the 0th index in each element.
Then it compares them based on the 1st value in each element of the list and so on..
This results in the following output:

```
>>> numbers
[2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 6, 8]
```

If there would have been characters at the first index in each element, they would have been sorted based on their ASCII values.